# Enterprise library 3.1 installation issue on windows 7

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, enterprise-library

I am trying to install enterprise library 3.1 (May 2007), but it givesme the following error.
      the installer requires the .NET framework ver 2.0 which is not present on this computer)
i have also installed visual studio ultimate- 2010
now, what should i do to resolve this error?
should i install just .net 2.0? will it create any  issues if i do that.

Comment: The farthest back I'd ever go is Version 4.1.  DAAB 3.0/3.1 was hard to work with, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think this is a question for [superuser](http://superuser.com) webpage..

Second, all you need to do is install [.net 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=1639) and it will work. If not, install the [sdk 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=19988).